# Where does org.springframework.boot logback put the log file (${LOG_FILE})?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I'm trying to figure out where ${LOG_FILE} is defined.

See file-appender.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
File appender logback configuration provided for import, equivalent to the programmatic
initialization performed by Boot
-->

<included>
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file> <!-- THIS ONE ---------------------------------->

<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
                <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-0}</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>
    </included>
```

I don't see it defined in any xml in the springframework logging directory. And its certainly not defined in my semi-boilerplate logback-spring.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in `org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml` inside `spring-boot-<version>.RELEASE.jar` as follows:

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
```

It tries to find LOG_FILE as a file to send logs to; if not present, it tries to use the "spring.log" file in the directory LOG_PATH, if not present in LOG_TEMP, if not present in java.io.tmpdir property and finally, if not present, in "/tmp". In other words, if you don't define LOG_FILE by yourself, and you didn't set any of the other properties above, you'll find your logs in /tmp/spring.log file (and LOG_FILE has exactly that value).

You can override it by adding your own `<property name="LOG_FILE" value="...." />` in your file-appender.xml (or logback-spring.xml) file.

Into `org.springframework.boot.logging.logback` package you can find all the properties set by spring when you e.g. add a  `<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>` at the beginning of your logback config file.

I hope having answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

Usually by the file include
/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml（spring-boot-2.2.0）

${LOG_FILE} defined this way，base.xml by include file-appender.xml

```
<included>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</included>
```